# Querying image from MySQL server results in corrupt file

Tags: php, mysql

I am running into an issue when querying an Image that is stored as a longblob from a MySQL. I understand that this is not an optimal way to do this, but it is a requirement for the project I am working on.

The server that is running on my local machine is running and querying the data properly, but the live server doesn't return the images properly (the browser believes that the file is corrupted). The code is the same on both devices. The returned longblob from the server has the same `sum` as the files that was created on the local environment (both files have the same data in theory).

Are there any settings that could be enabled that would cause this to fail on a live server vs a local environment?

### Simplified code for creating the image in the database

```
$productImage = "images/" . time() . $productImageImage["name"];
move_uploaded_file($productImageImage["tmp_name"] , $productImage);
$productImageImage = file_get_contents($productImage);

$query = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO product (productImage) VALUES (?)");

$query->bind_param("s", $ProductImageImage);

$result = $query->execute();
```

### Code for displaying the file

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
include 'include/db_connection.php';

function getId(){
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    $selected = $_GET['id'];
    return $selected;
}

function alt_getImage($connection){
    $s = getId();

    $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT productImage FROM product WHERE productId = ?");
    $query->bind_param("i", $s);
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->get_result();
    return $result;
}

function createImage($connection, $id){
    if ($id != null){
        $result = alt_getImage($connection);

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        echo $row["productImage"]; 
        $connection->close();
    }
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

$connection = createConnection();

createImage($connection, $id);

?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it actually be `$query->bind_param("b",$ProductImageImage);` ?

Comment: Use the Network tab and check the raw response, make sure there's nothing extra being returned before or after the image data, like PHP warning messages.

Comment: Are you sure that all stored images are jpg?

Comment: @maio290 I would agree, but why would that fail on a server but not on a local environment? (Unfortunately I tested it and it didn't impact it).

Comment: @Shadow I am currently testing it using nothing but jpg images, so it shouldn't fail.

Comment: You state being simplified code, but did you not close off `$s = 1` < that?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah sorry there is a lot more going on in the actual code, I cut down and redefined some of the variables to isolate the area of interest without showing too much unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @Barmar I can definitely do that, but I'm not sure how to do it with an image.

Comment: The image data should just be random junk. Something extra will probably be plain text or HTML.

Comment: @Barmar from what I can see there isn't any data being sent from the server, it sends an empty response.

Comment: I can't see any reason why that would happen if the query is successful.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah that is why I am confused, as I can run the command `"SELECT productImage FROM product WHERE productId = 11"` in mysql and it will run with a response that matches the output for the image, but it won't run when in the browser.

Comment: You may have simplified the code too much, and the problem is in the code you omitted.

Comment: @Barmar I have added the complete code for displaying the file

Comment: Are you sure you're sending the correct ID in the URL? You should add error checking to the code to make sure the query returned a result.

Comment: Ok. Well seeing your code again, I noticed that you're inserting the data using the "s" parameter, meaning a string. Are you sure you didn't mean using "b" instead, for "blob"? Maybe that's all that is wrong here. You are inserting a text string equivalent to the binary data you wanted stored in the first place, am I right?